# Iterating through csv and passing into request one by one

Tags: python, csv, python-requests

I am trying to make a program that iterates over a CSV file that only has one column and trying to pass it on as a request one-by-one, as the API can only handle one at a time.

This is the script so far:

```
import requests,csv
with open(r'C:/Users/Desktop/123.csv') as x:
reader = csv.reader(x)
for row in reader:
    print (row[0])
    r = requests.post("xxxyyyy.com",
    data={
        "ID": "xxx",
     },
    headers={
        "Authorization" : "xxx",
        "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Accept": "application/json",
    })
    r_dict = r.json()
    print(r_dict)
```

My problem is I do not know what to use to iterate over the CSV file and how to pass the string on as a JSON and then send it.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, just pass `row[0]` to the request's payload instead of printing it:

```
import csv
import requests

with open(r'C:/Users/Desktop/123.csv') as x:
    reader = csv.reader(x)
    for row in reader:
        r = requests.post("xxxyyyy.com",
                          data={
                              "ID": row[0],
                          },
                          headers={
                              "Authorization": "xxx",
                              "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                              "Accept": "application/json",
                          })
        r_dict = r.json()
        print(r_dict)
```

Comment: Thank you very much thisd helped a lot!
Now the situation is that i get a response from the server, but i think it is sending only one row and not multiple ones one after the other.
Is there a method to execute each row of the loop in post json?